# The tangent curve to Bessel functions?

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

Consider a function from the Bessel family, for concreteness say $f(x) := J_0(x)$, depicted in blue below (the question can be asked for any order of the first or second kind):

[image]

I'm interested in the orange tangent curve to the function. That is, an analytic, decreasing, convex (possibly even completely monotonic) function $g(x)$ that always upper bounds $f(x)$ and meets the function (with a matching derivative) once for each oscillation (the intersection points converging to the local maxima of $f$ as $x$ grows).

We know from the asymptotics of the Bessel function that $g(x)$ asymptotically behaves like $\sqrt{2/(\pi x)}$. But is there an explicit exact expression known in the literature, in any form (in terms of special functions, as a series expansion, integral form, etc)?

In general, what are the known techniques to approach questions of this kind (deriving tangent curves to oscillating functions, or even proving that they exist)?

Comment: Certainly there are infinitely many such functions. Maybe one has add some simplifications constraints, like monicity, little oszillation or curvature..

Comment: For the Bessel function $J_0(x)$, see Lemma C.2 of this paper: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/IPNR.pdf. They show that $|J_0(x)| \leq \min\{1, \sqrt{2/\pi |x|}\}$. Of course, this is not quite the same thing as the tangent curve, but perhaps it's good enough?

Comment: @hansel: I'd ideally like the curve to be completely monotonic, or at least be convex. With that, I don't see how there can be infinitely many.

Comment: @Peter: I'm interested in the exact curve but in any nontrivial form (series, integral form, etc).

Comment: In your case of the Bessel function a good choice appear to be $|J_0(x)+iY_0(x)|$. This has to be proved, but the figure with Mathematica is spectacular.  Perhaps this is how you get your figure.  These are the Hankel functions.

Comment: Actually, my figure is simply $\sqrt{2/(\pi x)}$. Although it generally has the expected look, it is not the solution to the problem (it may be only a first-order approximation of the tangent curve, and the question is what the correction terms would be).

Comment: @juan: Hmm, the absolute value of the Hankel function indeed seems spectacular. Could that be the exact solution?

Comment: A better key-word might be "envelope", rather than "tangent"...

Comment: Envelope is usually defined with respect to a family of functions, for example when we vary the parameter n in J_n(x) and consider the resulting curve. This is not the same object.

Comment: Envelope is usually defined with respect to a family of functions, for example when we vary the parameter n in J_n(x) and consider the resulting curve. This is not the same object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

juan's suggestion of the Hankel function seems great.
Here is $J_0(x)$ and $u(x):=|J_0(x)+iY_0(x)|$.
[image: graph]
Of course $u(x) \ge J_0(x)$ everywhere and $u(x) = |J_0(x)|$ at all the zeros of $Y_0(x)$.  For asymptotic properties of $u(x)$, from Maple I get asymptotics
$$
u(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}+O(x^{-3/2})\qquad\text{as } x \to \infty
$$
which explains the good fit in the picture of the OP.

For example, At the zero $x_0 = 19.64130970$ of $Y_0(x)$, we have
$$
J_0(x_0) = u(x_0) = 0.180005\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x_0}} = 0.180034 ,
$$
a very close fit.

Comment: Thank you. It can also be verified, from $|H_0(x)|=\sqrt{J_0(x)^2 + Y_0(x)^2}$, and directly taking the derivative, that the derivatives also match at every root of $Y_0(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

To complete your answer, you could note note that a a consequence of Nicholson's integral identity, proved in Watson's book, section 13.73. 
is that
if $x\geq n\geq 0$ then  fact 
$$
\left|H_n(x)\right|\left(x^2-n^2\right)^{1/4} \text{ is an increasing function}
$$
whereas if $n>\frac{1}{2}$ and $x>0$
$$
\left|H_n(x)\right|\sqrt{x}
$$
is a decreasing function.